# Question title overlap in new design when title is longer

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, title

Today I noticed that in new design view count is getting overlapped with question title on scifi.se for longer title:

[image]

But it's not site specific as same problem happen in Beta site too ( Hinduism.se):

[image]

That's why asked in main meta.

Comment: No repro on Chrome 69, Windows 10, 100% zoom level, normal DPI. For the sake of completeness, could you also mention Browser version, OS version, zoom level, and whether you're using High DPI or not (ignore this if it's not applicable)?

Comment: Chromium Web Browser

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if [SE officially supports Chromium or not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/241919) though...

Comment: I also found the same problem on the Safari browser....See my post linked on the right.

Comment: Cross-site dupe of [Questions' titles break free!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374026/4642212) on Meta.SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using an older version of Chromium? This should be fixed after the next build, assuming it's the same issue as [Rendering on Safari browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315847/rendering-on-safari-browsers).