# Rendering on Safari browsers

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, page-rendering

**Rendering of text on Home page Safari browser**

I've noticed over a course of a week or so that the rendering of the question titles on the **Home** page on MacOs Safari browser is not so satisfactory, resulting in overlapping words with the reputable attributes on the left. Is anyone else having this problem? The formatting on the **Questions** page is, however, rendering fine and I've checked both pages on firefox in the same system and it appears fine. I've seen the problem in both physics and math stack exchanges.

[image]

Comment: @Glorfindel   Yes indeed, a possible duplicate, I transferred my question from physics meta after their move to the new layout but only realised just now the problem persisted on math too. The comments in that post indicate the problem is also appearing on Chrome too.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which Safari version you're using, but I assume it's Safari 9? I can reproduce this in that version, but not in Safari 10. And indeed it looks like a typical issue that early flexbox implementations had. We don't technically support Safari 9 anymore, but the fix for this is simple, so I've added it. After the next build this should no longer happen.